# how to use mutt to attach and send files recursively

Tags: mutt

I would like to attach all .csv files from /home/john recursively, something like the following would be fine but only attaches all .csv files from /home/john/ it doesnt include all the sub folders of /home/john/

```
mutt  -s "all csv files" me@mail.com -a /home/john/*.csv < /home/john/message.txt
```

but what if I can do this and if there happens to be a .csv file in one of the sub folders with the same name?  eg /home/john/1.csv and /home/john/tom/1.csv what will happen? will it still be attached?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that command wont't find *.csv in subdirectories. You may want to use find and xargs, something like this:

```
find /home/john -name \*.csv | xargs mutt  -s "all csv files" me@mail.com -i /home/john/message.txt -a
```

I *think* -i would have the same effect as < from the file.